# Invalid Cast Exception, json, windows phone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

Hi Why am i getting an inalid cast exception?

```
    public class RootContainer2
    {
            [DataMember]
            public string StopName { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string StopId { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string Stop { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public ObservableCollection<Stops> Stops { get; set; }
    }

        private void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textRouteId.Text = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["name"];

            string myvar = textRouteId.Text;

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                Uri uri = new Uri("websiteurl");
                webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
                webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;

            try
            {
                ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootContainer2));
                RootContainer2 rootContainer = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as RootContainer2;
                foreach (Stops em in rootContainer.Stops)
                {

                    string df = em.StopName;
                    string dt = em.StopId;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is the json output which I am trying to read but I get an invalid cast exception.

```
{"RouteId": "1231", "RouteName":"1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak", "Stops": [ { "StopId":"6882", "StopName":"Swanborough Drive", "OperatorsCode4":"bridmpj", "Lat":"50.8326729229821", "Lng":"-0.103217996656901" } , { "StopId":"6883", "StopName":"Haybourne Road", "OperatorsCode4":"brimapm", "Lat":"50.8317788816436", "Lng":"-0.10486427645364671" } , { "StopId":"6884", "StopName":"Coolham Drive", "OperatorsCode4":"brijtwm", "Lat":"50.829695439856089", "Lng":"-0.10512229365031489" } , { "StopId":"6885", "StopName":"St Cuthmans Church", "OperatorsCode4":"briapdg", "Lat":"50.8283233642578", "Lng":"-0.104808002710342" } ,
```

Plus the class in stops.cs :

```
public class Stops
{
    public string StopId { get; set; }
    public string StopName { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

So after creating my own url and then testing the data, it's something to do with the URL that I was given I think. Just doing further testing.

Edit 2

If i put the data into a text file and debug the data, it works if i do the following.

the end of the feed is like this:

"Lng":"-0.277833998203278", "" } ] }

If  i remove the , and "" then it works. but how do i stop it getting there in the first place?

Comment: What is the *detail* of the exception?

Comment: When I debug it, when it reaches the end of this line:
RootContainer2 rootContainer = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as RootContainer2; 


it goes straight to the end and shows the error message which is simply 

"InvalidCastException"

Comment: That's because you're only showing the *message* of the exception. You should be able to get more information than that, such as the stack trace.

Comment: Ok, how would one be able to show the stack strace?

Comment: @HenryEdwards: Thanks for your second edit. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception could be caused by missing `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes, in particular on the `Stops` class. With the exception of Silverlight 5, `DataContract` is an opt-in model where all classes and properties that should be serialized have to carry a explicit attribute.

**Update**:

After your comment, I've looked in more detail into the JSON data you receive. You provide two pieces of JSON. If combined, they look like this:

```
{
    "RouteId": "1231",
    "RouteName": "1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak",
    "Stops": [
        {
            "StopId": "6882",
            "StopName": "Swanborough Drive",
            "OperatorsCode4": "bridmpj",
            "Lat": "50.8326729229821",
            "Lng": "-0.103217996656901"
        },
        {
            "StopId": "6883",
            "StopName": "Haybourne Road",
            "OperatorsCode4": "brimapm",
            "Lat": "50.8317788816436",
            "Lng": "-0.10486427645364671"
        },
        {
            "StopId": "6884",
            "StopName": "Coolham Drive",
            "OperatorsCode4": "brijtwm",
            "Lat": "50.829695439856089",
            "Lng": "-0.10512229365031489"
        },
        {
            "StopId": "6885",
            "StopName": "St Cuthmans Church",
            "OperatorsCode4": "briapdg",
            "Lat": "50.8283233642578",
            "Lng": "-0.277833998203278",
            ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm afraid this is simply invalid for JSON. As you found out yourself there is an extra comma and an extra emtpy pair of quotes close to the end. They make the difference between correct and invalid JSON. You can check it with an onlne JSON validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

The best solution would be if you could fix it on the server side. Otherwise it's probably best to try to fix the data before you passed it into the serializer.

Comment: Hi thanks, after putting the result in the validator even with the extra things in it's valid. but it can't be with this at the end - , ""

Answer (score 0):

`ReadObject()` takes a Stream (or some XML-related types) but `e.Result` is of type object.

Try:

```
RootContainer2 rootContainer = ser.ReadObject((Stream)e.Result) as RootContainer2;
```

**Edit:**  On second thoughts, that would probably throw an Invalid Parameter exception rather than an Invalid Cast.

Looks like the object being returned by `ReadObject()` is not castable to type `RootContainer2`.

Comment: It still skips the lines after that and shows the error message.

Comment: Yes, realised after posting that it would be a different error if that was the case. Shouldn't your RootContainer2 class have properties for RouteId and RouteName instead of StopId and StopName?

Comment: I am trying to get all the stops.

Comment: The `as RootContainer2` means you're taking the "object" returned by `ReadObject` and casting it to type RootContainer2 (from type object).  But if the format of your returned object does not match the format of your RootContainer2 class then it cannot be cast like that.

Comment: The stops will be in your Stops Observablecollection.

Comment: Try this: Paste your json sample into this page and click Generate to see what the matching c# class structure should be - http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Ok, i have done this on other json feeds, all outputing the same, so don't understand why this is causing a problem. In my Stops Observablecollection i have what I have put in the question at the bottom.

Comment: So does this exact JSON work with your other (working) code? And does an example of JSON from the other code work with this? Try to narrow down whether it's a difference in the JSON or a difference in the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have other json url which produce in the same way but with different objects, I will try putting in another feed, I will double check everything and then get back.